# dbt Incremental Model Issue with Snowflake Autoincrement Column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, auto-increment, dbt

I am encountering an error while utilizing an autoincrement column named `col_2` in Snowflake within my dbt incremental model. The column `col_2` is defined in Snowflake as:

`col_2(18,0) autoincrement start 1 increment 1 order`.

When executing my incremental model, I receive the following error message:

`invalid identifier 'col_2'`.

My model is structured as follows:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='col1',
    )
}}

SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM {{ ref('other_model') }}
```

It appears that DBT converts my model into something akin to:

```
...

when not matched then insert
    ("col1", "col2")
values
    ("col1", "col2")
```

However, col_2 is an autoincrement column in Snowflake, and I do not wish to insert values into it manually as Snowflake handles this automatically.

Could you please advise on how to resolve this issue?

I have attempted various methods to address this issue, but I am uncertain if I am heading in the correct direction. Here are the modifications in the model I've tried

1. on_schema_change: ignore
2. merge_exclude_columns = ['col_2']

- I dont want Snowflake's SEQUENCE or dbt's hash functions.

I am seeking a solution to ignore specific columns in the insertion query.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Idan, In dbt, all models (views, tables, incremental tables) are recreated on each full-refresh run. Only `source` tables can be created outside of the dbt project. dbt handles all model creation, meaning that you cannot create a table manually and then update it using dbt.
The concept of incrementality in dbt is to avoid table recreation on every `dbt run`. But without defining `is_incremental()` condition it doesn't provide much of a value. So, probably consider switching to the materialized='table' instead.